# Allow different user ability to modify time of wsgi file with touch -m

Tags: linux, apache, mod-wsgi, chmod, chown

I am using mod_wsgi which has the ability to dynamically reload my run.wsgi script when there's a change.  My app has many files, but only run.wsgi is monitored for changes.  Docs recommend to just 'touch' run.wsgi when any app files change - which does work well.

The problem I'm having is that my application is in a different (dedicated) user directory than my site's document root (for safety), and in certain circumstances, I need the user that owns the site to be able to 'touch' the run.wsgi file in the other user's directory (to force a reload of the app).  And site-user can't `touch -m /home/app-user/app/run.wsgi`

```
touch: setting times of ‘/home/app-user/app/run.wsgi’: Operation not permitted
```

I've already created a "common" group and updated permissions as such:

```
usermod -a -G commongrp site-user
usermod -a -G commongrp app-user
chgrp commongrp run.wsgi
chmod 770 run.wsgi
```

site-user is able to actually *modify* the wsgi file, but I don't want to do that.  I just want to kind of "fake" a modification of the file without *actually* modifying it.  Is there a safe way to do this with linux permissions, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use sudo to allow the site-user to run touch as the app-user.  Edit your sudoers file with `visudo` and create an entry like this:

```
    site-user    ALL=(app-user) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/touch
```

Then run it as app-user whenever you want with sudo:

```
    site-user$ sudo -u app-user /usr/bin/touch -m /home/app-user/app/run.wsgi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using daemon mode of mod_wsgi (which is the preferred setup), rather than embedded mode, and the daemon mode processes are set to run as the user you are able to access the system as, you could instead send a signal to the daemon mode processes to cause them to restart. Standard signals can use are `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` for orderly shutdown. If the daemon mode processes are configured with a graceful timeout, you can also use `SIGUSR1` and it will allow for a longer time for requests to finish before a process is shutdown.

If you are able to modify the WSGI script file, it is also possible to provide a function in it which decides whether daemon mode processes should be restarted before handling a request. That would entail coding up a function which checks timestamp on some other file to determine whether restart should be done.

For further help on this you are better off using the mod_wsgi mailing list.